# Setting Electron's language in Cypress

Tags: electron, cypress

Is it possible to set a language in headless mode(Electron)?

I need to run the tests headlessly with a specific language using Electron. I haven't been able to find information regarding this topic.

I don't know if it's even possible to set a language in Electron, I haven't been able to find something mentioning if it can or can't be done. 
Cypress documentation only mentions Chrome.

I have implemented it with Chrome, it works but I was requested to do it with Electron as a first option.

Has someone been in a similar situation?

Comment: SO is not the place for questions considered with documentation

Comment: I'm not asking for documentation, I'm asking if someone has been able to do it because all the documentation is related to Chrome and I have to do it with Electron first( if it's even possible). I'm hoping that someone with experience with Cypress can help me with this and that's why I'm aking here.